# How to validate login trough post request upon clicking the login button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, post, onclick

I'm having problems getting this code to validate when clicking on the login button.

** my html code **

```
<form action="abc.php" 
  method="post"  
  onsubmit="return jcheck();"> 
    <div id="id_box">
      <input type="text" 
             name="email" 
             id="id_text" placeholder="E-mail" >
      <div id="pass_box">
      <input type="password" 
        name="password" id="pass_text" placeholder="Password">
      <div id="submit_box">
        <input 
           type="submit" 
           id="sub_box" 
           onClick="click_event()" 
           value="Login">
```

**my javascript code:**

```
  function click_event(){ 
    jcheck();
    function validate_ID(){
      var email = document.getElementById('id_text');  
      var filter = /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){1,}@threadsol\.com$/;  
      var filter1 = /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){1,}@intellocut\.com$/;  
      var flag=0;  
      if (filter.test(email.value)==false 
        && filter1.test(email.value)==false ) {
        $('#warn_pass').html("Enter Valid Email or Password");
        $("#e_asterics").html(""); 
        return false;
      } else 
        return true;
      }
  function validate_Pass() { 
    var pass =document.getElementById('pass_text');
    var filter =  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s). 4,}$/; 
    if (filter.test(pass.value)==false ) {
      $('#warn_pass').html("Enter Valid Email or Password");
      $("#p_asterics").html("");
      return false; 
     } else 
       return true;
     }
   function jcheck();
     $("#e_asterics").html("");$("#p_asterics").html("");     
     $('#warn_text').html("");$('#warn_pass').html("");
     var name = jQuery.trim($("#id_text").val());var pas = jQuery.trim($("#pass_text").val());
     if ((name.length == 0) && (pas.length == 0)) {
       $('#warn_text').html("*Indicates required field");
       $('#warn_pass').html("* Indicates required field");
       $("#e_asterics").html("*");$("#p_asterics").html("*"); } 
     else if (name.length == 0)) { 
       $("#e_asterics").html("*");
       $("#p_asterics").html("");
       $('#warn_pass').html("Email Id Required");
     }  else if ((pas.length == 0)) {
       if(name.length != 0) 
     {
       validate_ID();
     } else {
       $("#e_asterics").html("*");  
       $('#warn_text').html("Enter Email Id");
     }

     $("#p_asterics").html("*");
     $('#warn_pass').html("Password Required");


   }
 }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: This is imposible to read.

Comment: sir , please help me...

Comment: Shorten your header to only include the question and explain the problem in the question body. And Ill se what I can do.

Comment: Please describe better why the login is not working.

Comment: Please include more detail about the surrounding settings in what html file does the code go.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should always indent your code so errors are easier to find. I helped you do a bit of indenting and there are a lot of problems in the code. One thing you are doing wrong is you need to close functions, else branches and html tags.

All HTML tags should end with an end tag or be closed immediately. 
Example `<div></div>` or `<div />` if you don't do this the browser may render your page differently on different browsers. You have missed this on your input tags you divs and your form tag. Perhaps you should check the whole html document for more of these errors.

Functions should in javascript should always look like this

```
function name(parameters, ...) {

}
```

or like this

```
var name = function(parameters, ...) {

}
```

the the name and parameters may vary but generally the function should look like this.

if statements else branches and else if branches should all have enclosing brackets for their code.

```
if () {
  //code
} else if () {
  //code
} else {
  //code
}
```

If you do not close start and close else brackets the javascript will behave in very strange and unexpected ways. In fact i think your code might not even compile.

If you are using chrome please press `Ctrl + Shift + J` and look in the Console tab. You should see some error messages there. When you click the submit button.

Also using `onClick` on the submit button may be dangerous as I don't think this blocks submit. A better way to achieve the requested functionality is probably to either use a button type input and go with `onClick` or use the `onSubmit` function on the form. You are currently using both and its really no way to tell if `click_event` or `jcheck` will run first. Perhaps you should debug and see in which order the function calls happen. You can use chrome to debug by pressing `CTRL + Shift + J` and setting debug points in the Source tab.

You have a minor stylistic error as well where you compare the result of the regexp `test()` with `false`. The return value of test is already a Boolean and does not need to be compared.

Here is a guestimation of how the HTML should look. Its hard to say if its right as I have no more info to go on than your code and it has a lot of problems.

```
<form action="abc.php" method="post" onsubmit="return jcheck();"> 
    <div id="id_box">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="id_text" placeholder="E-mail" />
    </div>
    <div id="pass_box">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="pass_text" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div id="submit_box">
      <input 
         type="submit" 
         id="sub_box" 
         value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is what the js might look like. Here the missing brackets makes it difficult to tell where functions should end so I have had to guess a lot.

```
/* I find it hard to belive you wanted to encapsule your functions inside the 
click_event function so I took the liberty of placing all 
functions in the glonbal scope as this is probably what you inteneded. 

I removed the click_event handler as it only does the same thing as the onSubmit.
*/
function validate_ID() {
  var email = document.getElementById('id_text');  
  var filter = /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){1,}@threadsol\.com$/;  
  var filter1 = /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){1,}@intellocut\.com$/;  
  var flag=0;  
  // Or feels better here as there is no way the email ends with bot @intellocut and @threadsol
  // It also feels strange that these are the invalid adresses maby you messed up here and should change
  // the contents of the else and the if branch.
  if (filter.test(email.value) || filter1.test(email.value)) {
    $('#warn_pass').html("Enter Valid Email or Password");
    $("#e_asterics").html(""); 
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
// This funcion is not used Im guessing you should have used it in
function validate_Pass() { 
  var pass =document.getElementById('pass_text');
  /* The filter below could cause problems for users in deciding password unless 
     you tell them some where what the rules are. 

     It was missing a { bracket before the 4 at the end that I added make sure
     it is right now. If you are going to use the code.
  */
  var filter =  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s). {4,}$/; 
  if (filter.test(pass.value)) {
    $('#warn_pass').html("Enter Valid Email or Password");
    $("#p_asterics").html("");
    return false; 
  } else {
   return true;
  }
}

/* There are betterways to deal with multiple validation than chaining them like
   this but Im guessing this will work. Im guessing that if you want to use the 
   password validation you should call it some where in this  function. 

   like so 'validate_Pass()'

*/
function jcheck() {
  $("#e_asterics").html("");$("#p_asterics").html("");     
  $('#warn_text').html("");$('#warn_pass').html("");
  var name = jQuery.trim($("#id_text").val());var pas = jQuery.trim($("#pass_text").val());
  if ((name.length === 0) && (pas.length === 0)) {
    $('#warn_text').html("*Indicates required field");
    $('#warn_pass').html("* Indicates required field");
    $("#e_asterics").html("*");
    $("#p_asterics").html("*"); } 
  else if (name.length === 0) { 
    $("#e_asterics").html("*");
    $("#p_asterics").html("");
    $('#warn_pass').html("Email Id Required");
  }  else if (pas.length === 0) {
    if(name.length !== 0) {
      validate_ID();
    } else {
     $("#e_asterics").html("*");  
     $('#warn_text').html("Enter Email Id");
    }
  }
}
```